# Symfony webpack encore require

Tags: symfony, webpack, requirejs, webpack-encore

I have this code

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>          
     <head>
     <script src="../dist/app.js"></script>   <-- webpack build here

        // how can I do a require() here, from something
        // inside the Webpack build?

     </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
    </html>
```

webpack.config.js

```
var Encore = require('@symfony/webpack-encore');

Encore
    // the project directory where compiled assets will be stored
    .setOutputPath('public/build/')
    // the public path used by the web server to access the previous directory
    .setPublicPath('/build')
    .cleanupOutputBeforeBuild()
    .enableSourceMaps(!Encore.isProduction())
    // uncomment to create hashed filenames (e.g. app.abc123.css)
    // .enableVersioning(Encore.isProduction())

    // uncomment to define the assets of the project
    .addEntry('js/app', './assets/js/app.js')
    .addEntry('homepage', './assets/js/homepage.js')
    .addStyleEntry('css/appLess', './assets/css/app.less')
    .addStyleEntry('css/app', './assets/css/global.scss')

    // uncomment if you use Sass/SCSS files
    .enableSassLoader(function(sassOptions) {}, {
                // resolveUrlLoader: false
     })
    .enableBuildNotifications()

    // uncomment for legacy applications that require $/jQuery as a global variable
    .autoProvidejQuery()
;

module.exports = Encore.getWebpackConfig();
```

Symfony ^4.0

For ajax loaded content with javascript is necessarily to run js from template , or what is best practicle ? 
Example i load form in ajax with select2 now i have js in template it use requirejs then init select2